# What is the difference between a TC-series and C-series protocol droid?

Tags: star-wars, droids

Wookieepedia and the canon source books have not helped me in this matter. The TC-series and C=series protocol droid seem to be the same height, and look the same. Is there a difference between them that I'm missing?

Comment: Just random thought: Could the T stand for translator?

Comment: C-series can translate to. C-3PO is the primary example of that.

Comment: One has a girl's voice and one a boy's?  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In Legends, [TC-series](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/TC-series_protocol_droid/Legends) droids were a protocol droid line produced by Cybot Galactica. They closely resembled the 3PO-series* protocol droids, and were sometimes referred to as TC-3PO protocol droids. The main difference was that TC-series droids were mostly created to serve on space stations, whereas 3PO-series droid were more environmentally eclectic. (It should be noted that due to his rebuild, C-3PO more closely resembled a TC-series droid than a 3PO-series droid)

We have not seen an appearance of these droids in Canon since the decanonization of the EU, and the above difference was never explicitly mentioned on screen (*The Phantom Menace* and *Star War: The Clone Wars*, both of which are of course is still Canon). So currently there is no practical difference and they can be assumed to be different versions of the same basic model.

---

*<sub>The droids you call "C-series" are actually 3PO-series droids. I don't know why.</sub>